# How to run "watch" command as "at" command pass argument

Tags: bash

I use "watch" command from cli it work separate but didn't work with "at" command.

```
watch -n 5 'sh script.sh'; #it works 

echo "watch -n 5 'sh script.sh'"| at now + 1 minute; # didn't work
```

I use watch command with following code from cli, like this:

```
watch -n 5 'sh script.sh';
```

script.sh has following line

```
echo "Running at testing $(date)" >> log.txt
...
last_upd_date=$(awk -F'","' '{print $6}' $output_file| sort | uniq | tail -2 | head -1)
....
python script.py
```

if i run only

```
watch -n 5 'sh script.sh';
```

i see added lines in log.txt.

But when run "watch" with "at" like this

```
echo "watch -n 5 'sh script.sh'"| at now + 1 minute
```

log file hasn't any changes

Comment: Why you need to watch and at in same time?? What is your desired output?

Comment: I want to run my script every 5 second,  but first run execute in specific time.
For example

     echo "watch -n 5 'sh script.sh'"| at 19:00

Comment: @user10869067 When you execute the command `echo "watch -n 5 'sh script.sh'"| at now + 1 minute`, did you see any error like "Can't open /var/run/atd.pid to signal atd. No atd running?" Could you try to run `ps aux | grep -i atd` to see if you have any atd daemon is running in process, like `/usr/bin/atd -f`?

Comment: @KevinCui
atd running. The "at" add jobs

    **$ watch -n 5 'sh script.sh' " | at -m now + 1 minute**
     OUTPUT is
   `warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
    job 132 at Mon Jan  7 10:52:00 2019`

and this is ps daemon

    **$ ps aux | grep -i atd**

   daemon    1584  0.0  0.0  16916   372 ?        Ss   10:44   0:00 atd

Comment: @user10869067 The job is added and it looks like atd daemon runs. Where did you run this command? Please check `script.sh` exists in the directory where you run `echo "watch -n 5 'sh script.sh'"| at now + 1 minute`.

Comment: @KevinCui The script exist in directory from where i run script.
Аs I already told, when i run  `$ watch -n 5 'sh script.sh' "`  it works ok, but when i use with **"at"** command it didn't work.

Comment: @user10869067ok, try to replace watch command by while loop? Like `echo "while true; do sleep 5; sh script.sh; done"| at now`

Comment: @KevinCui. 

Thanks for your help. I wanted to understand the reason why the previous command is not working.

But in the end, I can do it through a loop.